# How to do math operation on imported csv data?

Tags: python, arrays, list, math, iteration

I have read in a csv file ('Air.csv') and have performed some operations to get rid of the header (not important). Then, I used dB_a.append(row[1]) to put this column of the csv data into an array which I could later plot.

This data is dB data, and I want to convert this to power using the simple equation P = 10^(dB/10) for every value. I am new to Python, so I don't quite understand how operations within arrays, lists, etc. works. I think there is something I need to do to iterate over that full data set, which was my attempt at a for loop, but I am still receiving errors. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

```
frequency_a=[]
dB_a=[]

a = csv.reader(open('Air.csv'))

for row in itertools.islice(a, 18, 219):
       frequency_a.append(row[0])
       dB_a.append(row[1])
       #print(frequency_a)
       print(dB_a)

for item in dB_a:
    power_a = 10**(dB_a/10)
    print(power_a)
```

Comment: do you know [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org)? I think it could help you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on the answer @ed Jaras posted.

`power_a = [10*(db/10) for db in dB_a]` 
is not correct, since this divides by 10, and then multiplies by the same.

It should be: 
`power_a = [10**(db/10) for db in dB_a]`

Credits still go to @Ed Jaras though

Note: 
If you're wondering what this [something for something in a list] is, it is a list comprehension. They are amazingly elegant constructs that python allows.

What is basically means is [..Add this element to the result.. for ..my element.. in ..a list..].

You can even add conditionals to them if you want.

If you want to read more about them, I suggest checking out: 
http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Addition:
@k-schneider: You are probably doing numerical operations (dividing, power, etc. ) on a string, this is because when importing a csv, it is possible for fields to be imported as a string. 
To make sure that you are working with integers, you can cast db to a string by doing: 
`str(db)`

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, however I am still receiving the error: "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'".

Comment: @K.Schneider I added an answer to that problem to my post

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, item is the iterator, so you need to use that. So instead of:

```
power_a = 10**(dB_a/10)
```

use:

```
power_a = 10**(item/10)
```

A nicer way to create a new list with that data could be:

```
power_a = [10**(db/10) for db in dB_a]
```

EDIT: The other issue as pointed out in the comment, is that the values are strings. The .csv file is essentially a text file, so a collection of string, rather than integers. What you can do is convert them to numeric values using `int(db)` or `float(db)`, depending whether you have whole or floating point numbers.

EDIT2: As pointed out by @J. Meijers, I was using multiplication instead of exponentiation - this has been fixed in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, however I am still receiving the error: "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'".

Comment: I have edited the reply and have managed to test it as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: The simplest change would be `power_a = 10**(int(item)/10)`.

Comment: No problem. If this is all fixed, it would be great if you could accept an answer to "close" this.